# how to use filter or rewrite to change parameters to output desired permalink in child theme

Tags: wordpress

i have asked my theme provider, i want to change '**TEAM-MEMBER**' to '**AUTHOR**'. As like follow

Now link is : http://www.domain.in/**team-member**/authorname

but i want make this : http://www.domain.in/**author**/authorname

*my theme provider say that, Here is the code to update the team-member to author.*

```
<?php
add_filter( 'pgscore_register_cpt_teams', 'pgscore_extend_cpt_teams' );
function pgscore_extend_cpt_teams( $args ){

    // get current rewrite rules
    $rewrite_new = $args['rewrite'];

    // Change permalink slug to 'author'
    $rewrite_new['slug'] = 'author';

    // update rewrite rules with updated rewrite rules
    $args['rewrite'] = $rewrite_new;

    // return updated parameters
    return $args;
}
?>
```

*Add this code in the child theme (we assume that, you are using a child theme. If not, then create and use it).
We suggest using Child Theme for any customization. It can avoid losing any customization in the case of updating the theme.*

but i have put follow code in function.php in child theme, showing this syntex, expected error.

this is screen shot of error
[image: screen shot of error]

Comment: Did you read the error message at all? Remove the second `<?php` (on line 7) and it should work

Comment: oh thanks, my problem now solved.

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Remove  `<?php` on line number 7. You have start unnecessary php under php file. remove `<?php` and try to save again I hope it working well.